Parse XML with Xpath for unpaired tag
I want to parse following with Xpath in Python.
<h3>Province</h3>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="?k=*&program_language=ENGLISH&province_code=ON">Ontario (5853)</a>
<li><a href="?k=*&program_language=ENGLISH&province_code=BC">British Columbia (2096)</a>
<li><a href="?k=*&program_language=ENGLISH&province_code=AB">Alberta (1241)</a>
<li><a href="?k=*&program_language=ENGLISH&province_code=QC">Québec (921)</a>
<li><a href="?k=*&program_language=ENGLISH&province_code=NS">Nova Scotia (895)</a>
<li><a href="?k=*&program_language=ENGLISH&province_code=SK">Saskatchewan (847)</a>
<li><a href="?k=*&program_language=ENGLISH&province_code=MB">Manitoba (615)</a>
<li><a href="?k=*&program_language=ENGLISH&province_code=NB">New Brunswick (347)</a>
<li><a href="?k=*&program_language=ENGLISH&province_code=NL">Newfoundland & Labrador (305)</a>
<li><a href="?k=*&program_language=ENGLISH&province_code=PE">Prince Edward Island (120)</a>                 </ul>
    

my python code is following:
url=r'https://universitystudy.ca/search-programs/?k=&program_level_merged=&program_language=ENGLISH'

resq=req.get(url)
content=html.fromstring(resq.content)

category==content.xpath('//h3[text()="Area of Study"]/following-sibling::ul/li/a/text()')



while I expect to get a list of program names like following, my code return an empty list,
can not figure out what goes wrong with the code.
Business administration and management, general (520)
Computer science (289)
Mathematics, general (279)
Psychology, general (277)
Economics, general (250)
Biology/biological sciences, general (249)
Geography (241)
English language and literature, general (240)
Chemistry, general (220)
Political science and government, general (211)
History, general (200)


The xpath looks correct, however, the double equal sign is a comparison instead of an assignment. It should be category = content.xpath( ...

You should include your imports as well, and make sure your code snippet is actually a full, minimal working example

Your title says "XML", but this isn't XML, it is HTML. I wonder if your HTML parser has constructed a tree in which the elements are in the XHTML namespace?

I find the issue is due to following
resq=req.get(url)
actually, the server denies req.get request and return nothing for resq
The HTTP 403 Forbidden client error response status code indicates that the server understood the request but refused to process it.
